# Facing Linking Error--> Internal Error: [CoreUtil/General]: ApplyState - No allocation change for IAR Embedded Workbench

Tags: build, linker, ide, embedded, iar

How to fix the error ?
I am trying to build my code on IAR embedded workbench for RL78?D1A family, Build is success but facing below issue at linking.

Tool Internal Error:
Internal Error: [CoreUtil/General]: ApplyState - No allocation change
Internal Error: [CoreUtil/General]: ApplyState - No allocation change
Error while running Linker

tried with linker options in Project-->options, still facing the issue

Comment: You have triggered am internal error in the linker. This is either due to a big in the linker or to your code containing something that is outside the specifications of the language. My advice is that you contact Iar technical support.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.